# Pandas explode() for each \n new line in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I am trying to explode rows for each '\n' new line delimiter in row. The data has multiple columns to perform this function on.

Example:
**Input Data**

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| abc | V1\nV2\n |
| def | V1\nV2\n\V3 |

Output Expected

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| abc | V1 |
| abc | V2 |
| def | V1 |
| def | V2 |
| def | V3 |

I tried: df.explode(['Value']) but this displays the input dataframe as it is without any change. Also, In the given example it is only one column while the original data set has multiple columns (around 20-30 columns)

Answer (score 4):

First use `.str.strip` and `.str.split` to trim excessive whitespace from the ends and then each string by whitespace, then use `explode`:

```
df = df.assign(Value=df['Value'].str.strip().str.split()).explode('Value').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Name Value
0  abc    V1
1  abc    V2
2  def    V1
3  def    V2
4  def    V3
```

Note: if your strings have whitespace in them, use `.str.split('\n')` instead of `.str.split()`.

Comment: I was about to propose the same! I guess the reset_index() at the end remains optional.

Comment: Nice answer. Take care with `str.split()`, you should use `str.split('\n')` if there are strings with whitespaces.

Comment: @Corralien thank you! I added that note to the bottom of the answer :)

Comment: @Celius yes, it is optional; however, I decided to add it in case the OP gets confusing results later on from duplicated errors.

Comment: @richardec I tried this but there is no change to my data. So, my data is a time stamp entry, wherein whenever the user pushes the button a timestamp is recorded for that particular user, and each user's timestamp appears in one row for different days. The data does not have whitespace in form of ' ' only '\n' new line after each timestamp.... In the example table above 'Name' is user's name and 'Value' represents timestamp for one day

Comment: @Pallavi try `.str.split("\n")` or `.str.split("\\n")` - you may have to play around with the backslashes first, because with characters like the newline, it's hard to tell exactly what character you're actually using.